# whats up with this foreach in c#?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach, compiler-errors

(edit: Slight tidy of the code.)

Using foreach like this works fine.

```
var a = new List<Vector2>();

a.ForEach(delegate(Vector2 b) {
    b.Normalize(); });
```

The following however causes "No overload for method 'ForEach' takes 1 arguments".

```
byte[,,] a = new byte[2, 10, 10];

a.ForEach(delegate(byte b) {
    b = 1; });
```

Comment: If you don't need a delegate there, you should use normal `foreach` loop, not the `ForEach()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raw arrays have much less instance methods than generic collections because they are not templated. These methods, such as `ForEach()` or `Sort()` are usually implemented as static methods which are themselves templated.

In this case, `Array.Foreach(a, action)` will do the trick for the array.

Of course, the classical `foreach(var b in a)` would work for both List and Array since it only requires an enumerator.

However:

1. I'm not sure how you'd loop over a multidimensional array.
2. Your assignment `(b=1)` won't work. Because you receive a value, not a reference.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you just use a normal `foreach` loop to transform the data.  You're using a method that exists only on the `List<T>` implementation, but not on arrays.

Using a method for `foreach` really gains you nothing, unless for some reason you were wanting to do data mutation in a method chain.  In that case, you may as well write your own extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`.  I would recommend against that, though.

Having a separate `foreach` loop makes it clear to the reader that data mutation is occurring.  It also removes the overhead of calling a delegate for each iteration of the loop.  It will also work regardless of the collection type as long as it is an `IEnumerable` (not entirely true, you can write your own enumerators and enumerables, but that's a different question).

If you're looking to just do data transformations (i.e. projections and the like) then use LINQ.

Also keep in mind that with the array, you're getting a copy of the `byte` not a reference.  You'll be modifying just that `byte` not the original.  Here's an example with the output:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

Array.ForEach(numbers, number => number += 1);

foreach(int number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Which yields the output:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5

As you can see, the number += 1 in the lambda had no effect.  In fact, if you tried this in a normal `foreach` loop, you would get a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

You're using two different `ForEach`'es.

[Array.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zecdkyw2.aspx) in the `byte[,,]` example (though you're using it incorrectly) and [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) in the `List<...>` example.

Answer (score 1):

You've used syntax of `List.ForEach()` method for the array, but `Array.ForEach()` syntax is:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(
    T[] array,
    Action<T> action
)
```

One important point that array should be *one-dimensional* in order to use it in `Array.ForEach()`. Considering this I would suggest using simple `for` loop

```
// first dimension
for (int index = 0; index < bytesArray.GetLength(0); index++)             

// second dimension
for (int index = 0; index < bytesArray.GetLength(1); index++)             

// third dimension
for (int index = 0; index < bytesArray.GetLength(2); index++)
```

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know of a ForEach method that takes multi-dimensional arrays.**
If you want one, i think you will have to create it yourself.

Here is how to do it:

```
    private static void ForEach<T>(T[, ,] a, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
```

Sample program, using the new ForEach method:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[, ,] a = new byte[2, 10, 10];

        ForEach(a, delegate(byte b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        });
    }
    private static void ForEach<T>(T[, ,] a, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in a)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the `ForEach` method in the `Array` version, is not an instance method, it is statis method. You call it like this:

```
Array.ForEach(array, delegate);
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` has the first instance method.  Arrays do not.